# How should I attach sacrificial anodes to steel columns in concrete?

Tags: electrical, steel, retaining-wall, corrosion, galvanic-corrosion

Soldier pile retaining wall.

We're putting 25 foot long w8x48 beams into 16 foot deep holes and filling with concrete.

So the steel beam is encased in concrete.

I would like to increase their longevity by attaching a sacrificial (zinc ?) anode but I don't know where to attach it.

Can we weld them right on the outside surface of the aboveground exposed beam ?  Or does the sacrificial anode need to be buried in the soil and then welded to the beam with a copper wire ?

Or should we weld it to the beam under the ground, it will get encased in concrete and we will never be able to inspect or replace it - but would it be more effective encased in the concrete ?

EDIT: Lots of doubt expressed about the ability to use cathodic protection at all in an application like this that is not submerged in water but I draw your attention to the very common (universal ?) practice of attaching sacrificial anodes to steel propane tanks that are buried underground ... why is this different ?

Comment: Sacrificial entities need to be in contact with the same fluid medium as the oxidizing or oxidized part. You'd have to wet to the rust which in turn would damage your concrete and beam further, so bad move. Look for ways to keep moisture out, preventing rust and replace beams when they get too rusted.

Comment: @Abel : See comment below ... how do sacrificial anodes work for buried propane tanks ?  That is commonly done and the bag of zinc is "submerged" in the same soil as the tank ... but of course some amount of the tank is unburied under the valve riser ... so why can't we do the same thing with a steel beam ?

Comment: Rebar corrosion protection is done with galvanizing or epoxy type coatings on the rebar.

Answer (score 3):

Concrete itself protects steel from corrosion, which is why there are specifications of 2-3" **concrete cover** for steel reinforcing, depending on environmental exposure (3" for coastal.) See https://www.concrete.org/tools/frequentlyaskedquestions.aspx?faqid=668 and https://www.civillead.com/concrete-cover/

So I think you're barking up the wrong tree, here.

It's the 9 feet sticking out you should be concerned with corroding, and for that, they make Corten steel. Or you could just buy Corten **sheet pilings** to be driven in (with a pile driver, of course) and forget the concrete and holes.

Also, you should keep the steel 2-3" from the soil on the bottom and all sides of the hole (for instance by pouring a pad at the bottom of the hole before setting the steel in the hole.)

Comment: Steel rusts inside concrete.  It rusts differently, and perhaps more slowly, but it definitely corrodes - possible badly, depending on moisture and soil.  If you can protect the entire piece of steel with a sacrificial anode, then you don't care about above ground vs. below ground - the entire beam is one piece.  I have this already on my buried propane tank and it is a common practice - I just wonder what the details are for a beam encased in concrete vs. a tank buried in sand ...

Answer (score 0):

Sacrificial anodes only work if both the anode and the metal it is protecting are submerged in electrolyte wit a current path between them.

That works for boats. It works for water heaters. It does NOT work for cars, since they aren't immersed (one hopes). I am not at all convinced it would work for metal buried in concrete.

Comment: We buried our propane tank with a sacrificial anode attached to it - both "submerged" in the same dirt and the bag of zinc is attached with a wire.  That is why I am wondering if we need to bury the anode in the soil downhill from the wall and attach with a wire ?  Or does it need to be "submerged" in the concrete ?  That would be disappointing because then we could not inspect or replace them ... the ones we buried with the propane tank can be dug up and "refreshed" ...

Comment: A sacrificial anode must be replaced from time to time over the lifetime of a steel beam. Therefore the anode must be placed where it would be convenient to replace it. It would never be encased in the concrete or welded to the beam. Sacrifical anodes on steel boats are bolted to the hull. Sacrifical anodes protecting steel piers in seawater are connected by wires to blocks of steel immersed in the water near the pier. In this case the anode is the same metal as the steel pier and so a voltage is imposed on the system by a power supply. This forces the anode to corrode preferentially.

Comment: @JimStewart Thank you. As I mention elsewhere, it is common practice to bury propane tanks with bags of magnesium attached to the tank with wires.  So the tank and the anodes are "submerged" in the ground together.  Isn't this what I am suggesting with my steel beams ?  It seems like the exact same thing ... so I would think I "submerge" my sacrificial anodes in the earth next to the holes the beams are in and then connect with a wire ?

Comment: Google "cathodic protection" and read some articles. What is the contex of the steel post in concrete are you trying to protect?

Comment: @JimStewart Forgive me - what do you mean by "contex" of the steel post ?

Comment: Yikes. I meant _context_, that is, what is this steel post or beam supporting. But I see that you explain this in the post.

Comment: Unless this soil is extremely wet I doubt sacrificial protection is warranted. But this is a question that should be directed to professionals in the field of cathodic protection.

Comment: Agreed. This sounds like the kind of thing you can't afford to get wrong, hence the kind of thing you CAN afford to get an expert opinion on.

Comment: @JimStewart OK.  Given how common (universal ?) it is so install underground propane tanks with sacrificial anodes I just figured this was a more general knowledge set that people would have some experience with ... it seems like the same thing ...

Comment: I think the fact that anodes and concrete isn't common knowledge (but anodes with tanks and boats is) should be an indication that you're barking up the wrong tree. Secrets are not how the construction industry works.

Comment: Buried in wet soil is a corrosive environment. Buried in concrete, not so much.

Comment: https://www.structuraltechnologies.com/corrosion-control/?campaign=15312759566&content=630773086214&keyword=pile%20corrosion&gclid=CjwKCAjw36GjBhAkEiwAKwIWycBW0itZ88K9wk2t7P_anciAzn8sGGtKqlRZeNTJ22pdzMNptfK8sxoCyDkQAvD_BwE